# Obtener valor de una cadena después del 3er guion ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Quiero obtener solo la info del 3er guion

Ejemplo:  AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806  Resultado:3277806

Ejemplo2: 2204AA6-202A4/04-8.0-3277798    Resultado:3277798

Ejemplo3: 102124-2023/02-15.08-1    Resultado:1

Todos tienen 3 guiones pero la mayoria tienen distintos numeros de caracteres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta:

```sql
INSTR('AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806', '-', -1)
```

**EDIT:**

```sql
SUBSTR(
    'AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806',  
    INSTR('AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806', '-', -1) + 1,
    LENGTH('AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806')
      )
```

Comment: No funcionó, si o si, tiene que ser despues del 3er guion, la mayoria de los campos tienen disintos numeros de caracteres

Comment: Qué te sale? Se supone que con ello tomas la primera ocurrencia del guion empezando por el final de la cadena, o sea que no importa los caracteres que tenga la cadena.

Comment: Me devuelve INSTR(AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806, '-', -1) = 23, Solo quiero obtener el 3277806

Comment: Entonces funciona bien, ese es el índice en dónde empieza el último guion, luego tendrías que hacer uso de `SUBSTR`, por ejemplo. Lo acabo de editar.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda, habia conseguido algo asi, pero por alguna razon los numeros de caracteres era donde daba el problema

Comment: Genial! Si la duda fue resuelta márcala como respondida, así la comunidad sabe que existe una respuesta a esta pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: También puedes usar una expresión regular: `SELECT regexp_substr('AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806','-(\d+)',1,3,null,1) FROM dual`.

Comment: Si las dos formas funcionan sin problemas, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:
select  substr('AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806',instr('AAAAAAA-20242/01-19.04-3277806','-',1,3)+1)
from dual

select  substr('2204AA6-202A4/04-8.0-3277798',instr('2204AA6-202A4/04-8.0-3277798','-',1,3)+1)
from dual

select  substr('102124-2023/02-15.08-1',instr('102124-2023/02-15.08-1','-',1,3)+1)
from dual